# How to make chloropleth using Mapbox for Andriod, where the data comes in a GEOJSON

Tags: kotlin, geojson, mapbox-android

After getting a GEOJSON file which has all the boundaries of each country. From: https://datahub.io/core/geo-countries#data

How does one make a chloropleth using Mapbox, for a Andriod application being built using Kotlin.

```
private fun drawBoundaries(){
        mapboxMap.getStyle {

            try {

                val source = GeoJsonSource("geojson-source", URI("assets://countries.geojson"))

                it.addSource(source)

            } catch (exception: URISyntaxException) {

                Log.d(TAG, exception.toString())
            }
        }

    }
```

And I am guessing fill is as follows in the link: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/data-driven-styling/#fill

```
mapboxMap.getStyle {

val fillLayer = FillLayer("layer-id", "source-id")
fillLayer.setProperties(PropertyFactory.fillColor(Color.GREEN))

it.addLayer(fillLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `FillLayer` will be used and then you'll need to style it based on your data.

See https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/join-local-json-data-with-vector-tile-geometries and https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/update-by-zoom-level

Edit: Hm, looks like a video's missing for https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/join-local-json-data-with-vector-tile-geometries.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1B01g.jpg shows what the example looks like.